# Work with historical or data changes tracking with mongodb

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, nosql, mongoose-schema

I work in a little contruction company for little buildings,and i'm asked to create a sofware which can help anyone use a map to see al informations about the evolution of work.Example: We should build a Building that will take 3 year from now 2019,and averytime changes are made to updated informations about work status.So,for 2019 there some information,for 2020 and for 2021.As I'm using nodejs and MongoDB,i've a collection called `project` which has several attribute:`project_name,location,latitude,logitude,comment,....,created_at,updated_at,etc..` and for every changes the informations change for a given `project` but on of the requirement of the project is the `timeline` so that for each chosen year in the `UI`,i can display corresponding `data`.Should i create `another collection` that i'll call `project_history`?How can keep track of informations with mongodb?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use just that collection, I recommend you to filter the data by created_at or updated_at and that's all.

I can't imagine how to build a system with just 1 collection anyway.

Maybe you should think a little more about every aspect you need to build and create some more collections accordingly.

Let us know if you need more help, but to answer your question, I think it should be enough if you use the data you already have in that collection, and build the historical from there.

Comment: I have many collections,but my question about keeping history of all changes mades in a specific collection called `project`.What you've hasn't aswered my question in anyway,but thanks